# Explaining semantics around module imports within TypeScript declaration files

Tags: typescript

A couple months ago I wrote a simple TS declaration library `@types/datadog-winston` that [can be seen here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/datadog-winston). I used the typings locally, added them to the DefinitelyTyped repository, got through all the usual verifications and tests from that team and got my library published.

I am now trying to go back and actually use it and am running into a problem. When I try to add my `new DatadogWinston(options)` object to the list of `TransportStream[]` in order to use it as another transport for `winston` I get this error:

```
Services/Sandbox/sandbox/node_modules/@types/datadog-winston/index.d.ts:19:48 - error TS2339: Property 'TransportStream' does not exist on type 'typeof TransportStream'.

declare class DatadogWinston extends Transport.TransportStream {
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Services/Sandbox/sandbox/src/logging/logger.ts:32:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'DatadogWinston' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransportStream'.
  Type 'DatadogWinston' is missing the following properties from type 'TransportStream': writable, writableHighWaterMark, writableLength, _write, and 24 more.

transports.push(transport);
                ~~~~~~~~~
```

After a lot of looking around at how other winston transports work, I found they all seem to do slightly different things when importing the module `winston-transport`.

[Graylog2](https://github.com/namshi/winston-graylog2/blob/master/index.d.ts)

They did exactly what I did like this:

```
import * as TransportStream from "winston-transport";

declare class Graylog2Transport extends TransportStream {
  constructor(options?: Graylog2Transport.TransportOptions);
}
...
```

Then there is [winston-loggly-bulk](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/winston-loggly-bulk/index.d.ts) that did this instead:

```
import TransportStream = require('winston-transport');
```

When I changed mine from  being like `Graylog2` to be like `winston-loggly-bulk` by using

```
import TransportStream = require("winston-transport");
```

All of a sudden my build errors go away.  So my question is what exactly is the difference in what I am doing here? I know CommonJS was the old way of doing `const lib = require('mylib')` and ES6 has the new `import { Thing } from 'mylib'`, but what is this bizarre hybrid way of doing it where you have `import MyLib = require('mylib')` and why is this needed for this situation? I am having a hard time understanding the nuances between all these methods.

**UPDATE**

I tried installing the `winston-graylog2` library and use it and I get the exact same error! FYI I am using the latest version of TypeScript (v3.7.5). I have a feeling this is related to my local development, but I get the error both in VS Code (using TS Server extension) and when doing a tsc build from CLI directly.

Comment: Please show all of the imports leading up to the error. Ideally, post a [mcve] `package.json` and `index.ts` that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the module documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).

When you do `import * as TransportStream from "winston-transport";` you're importing the *module namespace object* for the module, a synthetic object that has all of the module's exports on it as properties.

When you do `import Transport = require("winston-transport");` you're using the TypeScript-specific single object export.

[I suspect (but don't know) that `import default as Transport from "winston-transport";` would also work.]

Comment: Thanks I will read this again (I had a while ago, but must not have retained much). Any chance you could explain how you would consume the library that would not result in a build error? Like I said that `winston-graylog2` library does the same and results in the same error, so I'm guessing I just need to import/require that library in another way as well.

Comment: In their "sample" they use `var WinstonGraylog2 = require("winston-graylog2");` but that doesn't seem to cause the problem because the variable `WinstonGraylog2` is of type `any`

Comment: @MattHintzke - I'm afraid I've just been called away (and I'm not an expert in this area), but that sounds right to me.